# Подстановка переменной c кириллическим текстом в python

Tags: регулярные-выражения, unicode, кодировка, python-2.7

Пытаюсь отматчить кусок текста в python 2.7 c с использованием re ,не могу установить кодировку текста и выдать нормальные результаты поиска ,вот пример :

1. Так текст вообще не матчится

   ```py
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   import re
   string='inline-block\">Проект</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; 4 минуты назад&nbsp;&nbsp; </div> <a class=\"b-post__ll\"><span class=\"b-icon b-icon__com b-icon_top_3\"></span>Нет ответов</a>'
   print (re.search(u'.*',u'inline-block\">Проект</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; 4 минуты назад&nbsp;&nbsp; </div> <a class=\"b-post__ll\"><span class=\"b-icon b-icon__com b-icon_top_3\"></span>Нет ответов</a>').groups())
   ```
2. А так выходит ошибка:

   ```py
   UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xd0 in position 14: ordinal not in range(128)
   ```

   ```py
   # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
   import re
   string='inline-block\">Проект</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; 4 минуты назад&nbsp;&nbsp; </div> <a class=\"b-post__ll\"><span class=\"b-icon b-icon__com b-icon_top_3\"></span>Нет ответов</a>'

   print (re.search(u'.*',unicode(string)).groups())
   ```

Основная задача искать вот такой паттерн `"Проект.*назад"` ,подскажите что я сделал не так и где можно подробно и понятно почитать о причинах почему не работает мой код ?

Comment: в сторону: используйте html-парсер, чтобы из html информацию изымать.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Все ,кажется разобрался ,причин было несколько:
Первое - нужно чтобы текст в котором будет производится поиск всегда был в юникоде,и если текст был изначально в utf-8 его нужно перевести в юникод
Второе - при указании регекспа нужно использовать двойные кавычки а не одинарные.
Третье - если хочешь использовать регексп с кирилицой его нужно обязательно собирать с помощью re.compile ,вот пример рабочего кода

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re
string='inline-block\">Проект</span>&nbsp;&nbsp; 4 минуты назад&nbsp;&nbsp; </div> <a class=\"b-post__ll\"><span class=\"b-icon b-icon__com b-icon_top_3\"></span>Нет ответов</a>'
regexp = re.compile(u'Проект.*назад')
print (re.search(regexp,unicode(string,"utf-8")).group(0))
```

Comment: совершенно не обязательно re.compile и одинарные кавычки использовать.

Comment: @jfs я проверил и так и так ,поэтому сделал такой вывод

Comment: плохо проверяли. Вот [рабочий пример без явного re.compile() и двойными кавычками](https://ideone.com/ofj9oZ)

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно использовать unicode для текста и шаблона:

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import re

text = u'<<<начало...\n...конецконец>>>'
print(re.search(u'(?s)начало(.*)конец', text).group(1))
```

[Результат](https://ideone.com/ofj9oZ):

```py
...
...конец
```

Если текст приходит из внешнего источника (файл, сеть, база данных) в виде байт, то следует прямо на границе в unicode его преобразовывать. К примеру, чтобы прочитать файл с диска, используя `utf-8` кодировку:

```py
import io

with io.open(filename, encoding='utf-8') as file:
    text = file.read()
```